# What is the intuitive meaning of left multiply elemantary matrix as a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

What is the intuitive meaning of left multiply elemantary matrix, say $E_1,E_2,E_3$? Since an elementary matrix is a "matrix"(for example, $\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}k&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$, etc.), then it must corresponding to a linear transformation. Then what is the intuitive meaning of applying such linear transformation?

Comment: What are are talking about? The matrices containing some $k$ are certainly not elementary.

Comment: The last one you mentioned is called [shear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping)

Comment: @ProfessorVector Actually, the matrix containing *k* is a [row-multiplying elementary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Row-multiplying_transformations).

Comment: @edm See the answer for an example of a shear.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on Hoffman & Kunze's *Linear Algebra.*

Algebraically, left multiplication of another matrix $A$ by an elementary matrix performs a single elementary row operation on $A.$ There are three elementary row operations:

1. multiplication of one row of $A$ by a non-zero scalar $k$,
2. replacement of the $r$th row of $A$ by row $r$ plus $k$ times row $s$, $s$ ≠ $r$, and
3. interchange of two rows of $A$.

Your first matrix interchanges the first and second rows of $A,$ while your second matrix multiplies the first row of $A$ by $k.$

For an example of a geometric interpretation, consider vectors $[a, b]^t$ in the Euclidean $xy$-plane. In this case, there are five elementary matrices:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a\\ b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b\\ a \end{bmatrix} & \mbox{ reflects the vector across the line } y = x,\\\\
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & k\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a\\ b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a + kb\\ b \end{bmatrix} & \mbox{ shears the vector horizontally by an amount proportional to } b,\\\\
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ k & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a\\ b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a\\ b + ka \end{bmatrix} & \mbox{ shears the vector vertically by an amount proportional to } a,\\\\
\begin{bmatrix} k & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a\\ b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} ka\\ b \end{bmatrix} & \mbox{ scales the vector horizontally, and}\\\\
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & k\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a\\ b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a\\ kb \end{bmatrix} & \mbox{ scales the vector vertically}.
\end{array}$$